# if statement makes my program in javascript stop working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My code was working fine till I added the if statement. Any help is much appreciated.

```
function calc() {
   var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('eersteGetal').value); 
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('tweedeGetal').value); 
    var answer = parseInt(a + b);
    var quotient = a % b;
    var bigger = '';                                                
    if(a >= b) {                                
        bigger = "Number A is bigger";              
    } else if(a <= b) {                             
        bigger = "Number B is bigger";              
    } else(a === b) {                           
        bigger = "Number A en B are equal";     
    }
    var paragraaf = document.getElementById('answer'); 
    paragraaf.innerHTML = answer;
    var paragraafTwo = document.getElementById('quotient');  
    paragraafTwo.innerHTML = quotient;
    var paragraafThree = document.getElementById('bigger'); 
    paragraafThree.innerHTML = bigger;
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Remove condition from `else` part

Comment: if you want third condition then remove `=` from `>=`  and `<=`

Comment: `else` is only exicuted if the other `if`/`else if` condition(s) do not return true so no condition is required for `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant put a condition in an ELSE.

Change your IF/ELSE-STATEMENT to this:

```
if(a > b ) {                               
    bigger = "Number A is bigger";              
}
else if(a < b) {                          
    bigger = "Number B is bigger";              
}
else {
    bigger = "Number A en B are equal";     
}
```

Comment: last condition  never reach

Comment: @FastSnail - Thanks for noticing.

Comment: remove `=` from first 2 conditions and add else

Answer (score 1):

Remove condition from `else` part.

```js
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('eersteGetal').value); 
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('tweedeGetal').value); 
  var answer = parseInt(a + b);
  var quotient = a % b;
  var bigger = '';                                                
  if(a > b) {                               
    bigger = "Number A is bigger";              
  } else if(a < b) {                          
    bigger = "Number B is bigger";              
  } else {
    bigger = "Number A en B are equal";     
  }
  var paragraaf = document.getElementById('answer'); 
  paragraaf.innerHTML = answer;
  var paragraafTwo = document.getElementById('quotient');  
  paragraafTwo.innerHTML = quotient;
  var paragraafThree = document.getElementById('bigger'); 
  paragraafThree.innerHTML = bigger;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="eersteGetal">
<input type="text" id="tweedeGetal">
<button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
<p id="quotient"></p>
<p id="bigger"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, removing the condition did the trick. Very greatful.

Answer (score 0):

You Missed "if" in last else

```
else(a === b) {                            
bigger = "Number A en B are equal";     
}
```

it should be

```
else if(a === b) {                            
bigger = "Number A en B are equal";     
}
```